# Why won't "wait until a'active" return when the signal a is assigned the same value as before?

Tags: vhdl

For a signal `a`, the attribute `a'active` is `true` whenever `a` is assigned to - *even if* its value does not change (i. e. the same value as before is assigned).

In the following example, the signal `a` is assigned its previous value, `'0'`, at 100 ns. `a'active` should therefore be true, but the `wait until a'active` statement in process `p1` does not return.

The wait statement in process `p2` waits for `a'transaction'event` *in addition to* `a'active` (to my understanding, the conditions should be equivalent). This wait statement does return, confirming that `a'active` is, in fact, true.

So why doesn't the `wait` statement in `p1` return, even though its condition is clearly fulfilled?

MWE:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library std;

entity vhdl_active_minimal_testbench is
end vhdl_active_minimal_testbench;

architecture rtl of vhdl_active_minimal_testbench is
    signal a  : std_logic := '0';

begin
    p1: process
    begin
        wait until a'active;
        report "p1: a'active";
    end process;

    p2: process
    begin
        wait until a'active and a'transaction'event;
        report "p2: a'active AND a'transaction'event";
    end process;

    stimulus: process
    begin
        wait for 100 ns;
        a <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;
        std.env.stop;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

ModelSim 10.5c output:

```
# Loading generic.vhdl_active_minimal_testbench(rtl)
# ** Note: p2: a'active AND a'transaction'event
#    Time: 100 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /vhdl_active_minimal_testbench
# Break in Process stimulus at [...]/test_vhdl_active_minimal.vhd line 29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, `a'transaction` is a signal (and is therefore added to the implicit sensitivity list of the process), whereas `a'active` is not a signal.

Your code is equivalent to

```
p1: process() is
begin
    wait until a'active;
    report "p1: a'active";
end process;

p2: process(a'transaction) is
begin
    wait until a'active and a'transaction'event;
    report "p2: a'active AND a'transaction'event";
end process;
```

p1 never fires after starting to wait: only signals can be used for a process to be sensitive to. Blank sensitivity lists will expand to all independent signals that are read in the process: these don't exist for p1.

p2 has a signal in a'transaction, which is a signal of type 'bit', which toggles each time there is a transaction, firing p2.

From the *Doulos VHDL Golden Reference Guide* (version 4.0):

> S'TRANSACTION A signal of type BIT which toggles whenever there is a
> transaction on S (A signal assignment creates a transaction. A
> transaction that causes a change in value is an event).
>
> S'ACTIVE TRUE if and only if there is a transaction (signal
> assignment) on S in the current delta.
>
> Gotchas!
>
> The attribute S'EVENT is not a signal, so should not be used in a
> context where a signal is needed to trigger a process. [..]

Same gotcha applies for 'active'.

Comment: user8352's answer is better (in line with both the standard and main simulators), but I cannot delete my answer because it's accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Because the OP's question contains a std.env.stop call we know the VHDL design specification is compliant with the 2008 LRM:

IEEE Std 1076-2008
14.7.3 Propagation of signal values
14.7.3.1 General

> As simulation time advances, the transactions in the projected output waveform of a given driver (see 14.7.2) will each, in succession, become the value of the driver. When a driver acquires a new value in this way or as a result of a force or deposit scheduled for the driver, regardless of whether the new value is different from the previous value, that driver is said to be *active* during that simulation cycle. ...

16.2.4 Predefined attributes of signals
[image: S'ACTIVE attribute definition]

The implication is `a'active` is true for any simulation cycle where `a`'s driver is updated regardless of whether the evaluated new value is different from the previous value.

There's also the matter of signals in the sensitivity list for the wait statement:

```vhdl
        wait until a'active;
```

10.2 Wait statement
(paragraph 3 in part):

> The sensitivity clause defines the sensitivity set of the wait statement, which is the set of signals to which the wait statement is sensitive. Each signal name in the sensitivity list identifies a given signal as a member of the sensitivity set. Each signal name in the sensitivity list shall be a static signal name, and each name shall denote a signal for which reading is permitted. If no sensitivity clause appears, the sensitivity set is constructed according to the following (recursive) rule:
>
> The sensitivity set is initially empty. For each primary in the condition of the condition clause, if the primary is
>
> > ...
> >     — An attribute name, if the designator denotes a signal attribute, add the longest static prefix of the name of the implicit signal denoted by the attribute name to the sensitivity set; otherwise, apply this rule to the prefix of the attribute name.
> >     ...

Yet when we simulate the report statement doesn't get executed (p1 never resumes from the wait statement).

Why?

10.2 paragraph 9:

> The suspended process also resumes as a result of an event occurring on any signal in the sensitivity set of the wait statement. If such an event occurs, the condition in the condition clause is evaluated. If the value of the condition is FALSE, the process suspends again. Such repeated suspension does not involve the recalculation of the timeout interval.

Which leads us to the definition of event:

14.7.3.4 Signal update
paragraph 3:

> The current value of a signal of type T is said to change if and only if application of the predefined “=” operator for type T to the current value of the signal and the value of the signal prior to the update evaluates to FALSE. If updating a signal causes the current value of that signal to change, then an *event* is said to have occurred on the signal, unless the update occurs by application of the `vhpi_put_value` function with an update mode of `vhpiDeposit` or `vhpiForce` to an object that represents the signal. This definition applies to any updating of a signal, whether such updating occurs according to the preceding rules or according to the rules for updating implicit signals given in 14.7.4. The occurrence of an event will cause the resumption and subsequent execution of certain processes during the simulation cycle in which the event occurs, if and only if those processes are currently sensitive to the signal on which the event has occurred.

There is no event causing process p1 to resume while the predefined attribute 'ACTIVE would return TRUE. The current value does not change by executing the assignment to `a` in the stimulus process.

If you were to assign a value different than the initial value provided in the signal `a` declaration in the stimulus process p1:

```vhdl
    stimulus: process
    begin
        wait for 100 ns;
        a <= '1'; -- WAS '0';
        wait for 100 ns;
        std.env.stop;
    end process;
```

process p1 would resume and the report statement would execute:

```
ghdl -a --std=08 vhdl_active_minimal_testbench.vhdl
ghdl -e --std=08 vhdl_active_minimal_testbench
ghdl -r vhdl_active_minimal_testbench
vhdl_active_minimal_testbench.vhdl:21:9:@100ns:(report note): p2: a'active AND a'transaction'event
vhdl_active_minimal_testbench.vhdl:15:9:@100ns:(report note): p1: a'active
simulation stopped @200ns
```

Note there is no guarantee the order wait statements of suspended processes are evaluated (process statements are concurrent statements).

14.7 Execution of a model
14.7.1 General
paragraph 3:

> For any given signal that is explicitly declared within a model, the kernel process contains variables representing the driving value and current value of that signal. Any evaluation of a name denoting a given signal retrieves the current value of the corresponding variable in the kernel process. During simulation, the kernel process updates these variables from time to time, based upon the current values of sources of the corresponding signal.

We don't get to peer into the kernel process, part of the simulator itself.

The underlying idea is events are caused by changes to the current value of a signal while active relates to update regardless of causing an event. A wait statement condition clause (**until** condition) isn't evaluated unless there is an event. VHDL simulation is event driven.

The *Doulos VHDL Golden Reference Guide* description of S'ACTIVE referenced in Don Fusili's answer is not causal.

Determining a change in the current value of a signal does not rely here on `a'transaction'event` which would entail a delta delay during simulation. S'TRANSACTION is a signal and it's updated current value is not observable in the same simulation cycle as S'ACTIVE without another update in value of S (here `a`,  which isn't updated in successive cycles with the same simulation time in this design model).